# while installing ruby i have an error on gem install json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

After installing ruby and divkit I have an error while downloading the package. It's a ssl certificate error and I tried almost every solution on net and nothing worked.

```
gem install json --platform=ruby

ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'json' (>= 0), here is why: Unable to
 download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0
 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed
 (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
```

Comment: Are you using `windows os` in your machine ?

Comment: I had similar issue long time ago, I had to change `https://rubygems.org/` to `http://rubygems.org/` but i am not sure it is still working.

Comment: are you in a proxy or office workstation... ?

Comment: office workstation

Answer (score 0):

We recently had this issue with some of the students in our training bootcamp and how i had them fix it as well as a lot of people in so is by using gem source --add http://rubygems.org if u dont want to have to do gem install json --source http://rubygems.org (or the name of any gem everytime) this will add or change your source to the non secure (http rather then https ) and this should work for you